# Problem setting the input and output in Spark with vector assembler (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, vector, input

I have a data set with 5408 columns, all of them are  printed like: 
 _c0|   _c1|   _c2|   _c3|   _c4|   _c5|   _c6|   _c7|   _c8|   _c9|  |-0.169|-0.025|-0.010|-0.041|-0.045|-0.069| 0.038| 0.014| 0.008|-0.014|.

I want to put all the columns together and put separate the label, but I have this error which means that my columns are not supported:
xception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type string of column _c0 is not supported.
Data type string of column _c1 is not supported.
Data type string of column _c2 is not supported.
Data type string of column _c3 is not supported.
Data type string of column _c4 is not supported.

I wanto to create a ML model, so fat I have:

```
Dataset<Row> csvData = spark.read()
                .option("header", false)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .csv("src/main/resou`enter code here`rces/K9.data");

        StringIndexer conditionIndexer = new StringIndexer ()
                .setInputCol("_c5408")
                .setOutputCol("_c5408Index");
        csvData = conditionIndexer.fit(csvData).transform(csvData);

//Cleaning data
List<org.apache.spark.sql.Column> list = new ArrayList<org.apache.spark.sql.Column>();
        for (String col : csvData.columns()) {
            list.add(when(csvData.col(col).equalTo("?"), 0).otherwise(csvData.col(col)).alias(col));
        }
        csvData = csvData.select(list.toArray(new org.apache.spark.sql.Column[0]));


    List<org.apache.spark.sql.Column> list_null = new ArrayList<org.apache.spark.sql.Column>();
    for (String col : csvData.columns()) {
        list_null.add(when(csvData.col(col).isNull(), 0).otherwise(csvData.col(col)).alias(col));
    }
    csvData = csvData.select(list_null.toArray(new org.apache.spark.sql.Column[0]));

    csvData = csvData.na().fill(0, csvData.columns());
        csvData.groupBy(col("_c5408"),col("_c5408Index")).count().show();

 ArrayList<String> inputColsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(csvData.columns()));
        //Make single features column for feature vectors
        inputColsList.remove("_c5408Index");

        VectorAssembler vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
                .setInputCols(inputColsList.parallelStream().toArray(String[]::new))
                .setOutputCol("features");

       `enter code here` Dataset<Row> modelInputData = vectorAssembler.transform(csvData)
                .select("_c5408Index", "features")
                .withColumnRenamed("_c5408Index", "label");
```

The error is when the Dataset modelInputData = vectorAssembler.transform(csvData) is written.

The Schema is

```
|-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c13: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c14: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c15: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c16: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c17: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c18: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c19: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c20: string (nullable = true)

c5408Index: double (nullable = false)
```

The data sets looks like

Comment: Can you add the result of printSchema() and show() after the ingestion, so we know better what the shape of the data is? - Thanks

Comment: @jgp Thanks! I change the information adding more things. I still dont know why is this error.